# WPF Xaml suggesions not working on VS2019 16.4.4

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a project (WpfControlLibrary1:WPF user control library) which includes MyDictionary.xaml. This dictionary includes resource definitions like :

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="AliceBlue" x:Key="MY_COLOR"/>"
```

I have another project(WpfCustomControlLibrary1:WPF custom control library).

WpfCustomControlLibrary1 references WpfControlLibrary1 to use styles. WpfCustomControlLibrary1 has App.xaml file like this.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfCustomControlLibrary1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfControlLibrary1;component/Dictionary1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And I have a UserControl1.xaml in WpfCustomControlLibrary1  like this.

```
 **<UserControl x:Class="WpfCustomControlLibrary1.UserControl1"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 d:DesignHeight="450"
                 d:DesignWidth="800">

        <!--Suggestion not working for MY_COLOR-->
        <!--Please open the solution in VS 2013 and see the Suggestions working-->
        <Button Background="{StaticResource MY_COLOR}" />
    </UserControl>**
```

Every thing is OK. But the problem is Static resource suggestions not working in VS2019.

I'm opening the solution with VS2013. Suggestions working in VS2013

Comment: Hello. I'm using vs2019 16.4.4. and the suggestions for static resources work well. If you have compiled the solution, the suggestions should show well. The only difference that I see with my code is that I reference the ResourceDictionary without pack://application. I use pack... with external libraries (nuget). I use <ResourceDictionary Source="/WpfControlLibrary1;component/Dictionary1.xaml" /> but I don't sure if this is the problem. If the problem continue, uninstall and reinstall visual studio.

Comment: I tried what you said but it still not working. When I tried this scenerio with  WPF application project type it working. When project type is "User control library" or  "custom control library" it not working

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe you have deactivated some of intellicode. Check visual studio options.